# Getting get from API in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So on component mount I need companyId, that code is handled in another file.
`import companyApi from 'qs-data-manager/Company';`

Further in the then of my componentMount

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    network
      .getJewelleryPriceSettings({
        entityId: this.state.entityId,
        entityType: this.state.entityType,
      })
      .then(data => {
        useEffect(() => {
           getCompanyIdFromApi();
        }, []);
```

and in this way my other code goes

```
const [CompanyIdFromApi, setCompanyIdFromApi] = useState([]);

async function getCompanyIdFromApi() {
  const companyId = await companyApi.getCompanyId(); //fetches id
  setCompanyIdFromApi(companyId);
}
```

this is then stored in other variable

```
const requestBody = {
  eentityId: CompanyIdFromApi,
  entityType: ENTITY_TYPE.COMPANY, // no error here
};
```

and finally I update this two fields in state in my class like this

```
class CompanyJewelleryPriceSettings extends Component {
  state = {
    // entityId: '-MnzS3lc9Qo8dmy1PWnB',
     entityId: requestBody.eentityId,
     entityType: requestBody.entityType,
    jewelleryPriceDisplayStatus: {},
  };
```

But I throw here some very weird error like this

```
 ERROR  Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

so somehow my way to get the data is not proper ig. Please help Thanks

Comment: Are you using useState inside class component? This is not allowed as hooks can be used only inside functional component.

Comment: then what can I do ? to do my task? just want a string that is given by another file into this file that's it.

Comment: Rewrite your code with only class components or functional components. Don't mix them.Functional components are the latest way.